Question on a research paper for solving the Poisson equation using a variational quantum algorithm
I am reading a research paper: "Variational Quantum Algorithm Based on the Minimum Potential Energy for Solving the Poisson Equation". [ArXiV]
In the paper, the authors try to solve the Poisson equation in Eq. $(1)$:
$$-\nabla^2 u(x) = f(x)\,.$$
They reformulate the problem of solving the Poisson equation into finding the minimum energy given by Eq. $(4)$:
$$E := \frac{1}{2} \int_{\Omega} \nabla v^* \cdot \nabla v d\Omega - \frac{1}{2} \int_{\Omega} v^* f d\Omega - \frac{1}{2} \int_{\Omega} f^* v d\Omega\,,$$
where $\Omega$ is the domain.
In this formulation, the function $v$ that minimizes $E$ is the solution $u$ of the Poisson equation in Eq. $(1)$. This energy function is then discretized in Eq. $(7)$ as:
$$E_h := \frac{1}{2} v^* A v - \frac{1}{2} v^* f - \frac{1}{2} f^* v\,,$$
where the matrix $A$ is explicitly defined in equations $(15)$ to $(17)$ for periodic, Dirichlet, and Neumann boundary conditions, respectively.
For example, $A_{Dirichlet}$ is defined as follows in Eq. $(16)$:
$$
A_\text{Dirichlet} :=
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & -1 &  0 & \cdots & 0 \\
-1 &  2 & -1 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & -1 &  2 & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & -1 \\
0 &  0 &  0 & -1 &  2
\end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times N}.
$$

Here is my question:
I think the quadratic form $v^* A v$ should represent $\int_{\Omega} (\nabla v)^* \cdot (\nabla v) d\Omega$. However, based on the structure of the matrices $A$ given in equations $(15)$ to $(17)$, it seems like $v^* A v$ represents $\propto v \cdot (-\nabla^2 v)$.
Am I misunderstanding the connection between $v^* A v$ and $\int_{\Omega} (\nabla v)^* \cdot (\nabla v) d\Omega$?
